# Why qualified path patterns accept constants, structs and enum variants even though the reference forbid those?

Tags: rust

> Path patterns are patterns that refer either to constant values or to structs or enum variants that have no fields.
>
> Unqualified path patterns can refer to:
>
> enum variants, structs, constants, associated constants
>
> Qualified path patterns can only refer to associated constants.

From [Patterns - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#path-patterns)

I created this example for this:

```
mod m {
    pub mod n {
        pub const CONST: i32 = 1;
        pub struct S;
        pub enum E {
            V,
        }

        pub struct A;

        impl A {
            pub const ASSOC_CONST: i32 = 2;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = 10;

    match v {
        m::n::CONST => (),
        m::n::A::ASSOC_CONST => (),
        _ => (),
    }

    let v = m::n::S {};

    match v {
        m::n::S {} => (),
    }

    let v = m::n::E::V;

    match v {
        m::n::E::V => (),
    }
}
```

And it compiles without an issue even though I use qualified path patterns. Shouldn't this fail for anything but associated constants in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qualified paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/paths.html#qualified-paths) are paths like `<T as Trait>::CONSTANT` and can only refer to trait-associated items, which are functions, types, and constants. The only one of those that can be used in patterns is constants.

All your paths are unqualified/simple.

Here's one that attempts to use a qualified path:

```rust
struct A;
struct B(i32);

trait HasType {
    type T;
}

impl HasType for A {
    type T = B;
}

fn main() {
    let b = B(5);
    let <A as HasType>::T(n) = b;
    println!("{n}");
}
```

It produces these errors:

```rust
error[E0575]: expected method or associated constant, found associated type `HasType::T`
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |     let <A as HasType>::T(n) = b;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: can't use a type alias as a constructor

error[E0658]: usage of qualified paths in this context is experimental
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |     let <A as HasType>::T(n) = b;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #86935 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86935> for more information
```

The linked issue is [Tracking Issue for "More Qualified Paths" #86935](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86935).

Answer (score 1):

This is not what the reference calls "qualified paths". [Qualified paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/paths.html#qualified-paths) are `<A as B>::C`.